# How to visualize the pointers in the code snippet?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, pass-by-reference, dereference

I am finding it difficult to visualize this piece of code. I cannot seem to find the ans to this.

I did get the ans for

```
printf("**r = %d\n",**r);
printf("**s = %d\n",**s);
```

but other variables are not matching the ans. Please help.

```
int f(int ** r, int ** s) {
    int temp = ** r;
    int temp2 = **s;
    int * z = *r;
    *r = *s;
    *s = z;

    printf("**r = %d\n",**r);
    printf("**s = %d\n",**s);
    *z += 3;
    **s -= 8;
    **r -= 19;

    return temp + temp2;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 80;
    int b = 12;
    int * p = &a;
    int * q = &b;
    int x = f(&p, &q);

    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
    printf("*q = %d\n", *q);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    printf("b = %d\n", b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Expected output:

```
**r = 12
**s=80
x=92
*p=-7
*q=75
a=75
b=-7
```

Comment: What output do you expect, and what do you get, instead?

Comment: **r = 12  **s=80  x=92 
*p=-7 *q=75  a=75   b=-7  is what you should be getting but I am mixing up a b *p and *q

Comment: I don't get you. Are you saying that this program is wrong? I am not sure as I was supposed to dry run this one but as it's was a ques from a online grader, I would suppose it works

Comment: I edited your question with the expected result from your comment. Is it correct? (if not, edit the question again adding both the expected result and the actual one) Because it is exactly what I get (and what is expected after analyzing your code). So, what's the problem? You don't understand why this is the returned result?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration the pointers `p` and `q` are passed by reference to the function `f`.

```
int x = f(&p, &q);
```

The pointer `p` points to the variable `a` and the pointer `q` points to the variable `b`.

```
int a = 80;
int b = 12;
int * p = &a;
int * q = &b;
```

Within the function `f` declared like

```
int f(int ** r, int ** s);
```

the pointer `r` points to the pointer `p` and the pointer `s` points to the pointer `q`.

Correspondingly in these declarations

```
int temp = ** r;
int temp2 = **s;
```

the variable `temp` is initialized by the value of variable `a` and the variable `temp2` is initialized by the value of the variable `b`.

You van imaging these declaration like

```
int temp = a;
int temp2 = b;
```

In this code snippet

```
int * z = *r;
*r = *s;
*s = z;
```

there are in fact swapped the the pointers `p` and `q` pointed to by the pointers `r` and `s`. That is after this code snippet the pointer `r` now points to the pointer `q` and the pointer `s` points to the pointer `p`.

You can imaging this like

```
*r = q;
*s = p;
```

The intermediate variable `z`

```
int * z = *r;
```

gets the value of the pointer `p`.

You can imaging this like

```
int * z = p;
```

This statement

```
*s = z;
```

did not change the value pointed to by `s` because before this statement the variable `s` already pointed to `p` due to preceding swapping the pointed values of the pointer `r` and the pointer `s`.

So these calls of printf

```
printf("**r = %d\n",**r);
printf("**s = %d\n",**s);
```

correspondingly will output the value of `b` and the value of `a`.

That is the output will be

```
**r = 12
**s = 80
```

As the pointer `z` has the value of the pointer `p` then after this statement

```
*z += 3;
```

the variable `a` will be increased by `3` and becomes equal to `83`.

In these statements

```
**s -= 8;
**r -= 19;
```

the variable `a` will be decrease by `8` and becomes equal to `75` And the variable `b` is decreased by `19` and becomes equal to `-7`.

At last the function returns the sum of the initial values of the variables `a` and `b`

```
return temp + temp2;
```

that is `92`.

In these statements in main

```
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
printf("*q = %d\n", *q);
printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("b = %d\n", b);
```

there is outputted the value returned by the function f

```
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

that is 92.

As the pointers `p` and `q` were swapped in the function then now the pointer `p` points to `b` and the pointer q points to `a`.

```
printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
printf("*q = %d\n", *q);
```

So these statements output

```
*p = -7
*q = 75
```

And these statements

```
printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("b = %d\n", b);
```

outputs the new values of a and b themselves that is

```
a = 75
b = -7
```

As for this statements

```
printf("**r = %d\n",**r);
printf("**s = %d\n",**s);
```

then for example the expression `*r` points to the pointer `p`. So dereferencing the pointer p like `*p`  that is the same as `*( *r )` you will get the lvalue of the variable `a`.